# Is it me, or does syntax highlighting not work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I used code blocks in [an answer](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/70/21) and the code isn't highlighted, although I specified the language (by writing ```rust). Is it a bug, is it expected behavior, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It hasn't been activated yet; if you [run this API query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=1000&filter=default&run=true) you can see the difference between Stack Overflow, which has the ["Prettify" Markdown extension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314554/295232):

[image]

and our site, which doesn't:

[image]

It makes sense to activate it here, so I hope staff will see this question and do so. Moderators can then [add default syntax highlighting for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/295232), so if a question is tagged [rust](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust), it will automatically get Rust-specific highlighting.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense for the plugin not to have been activated yet since the site only opened today. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Syntax highlighting is disabled by default, and is only enabled for sites that need it.

That said, given the topic of this site, syntax highlighting has now been enabled here (both on the main and meta sites).